# Issue with SMS manager in Android

Tags: android, smsmanager

I have the following code which asks for permission to send sms from a phone. When i launch the app for the first time, it asks for permission. When i grant it,it will send an sms. But when I close the app and try again, nothing happens when i click the 'Yes' button. I am not able to debug also. Somebody please advise.

```
public class AssignLanding extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView display,staffVie;
    private Button yesSure;
    private String resSlno,staffPhone,staffName,message;

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS =0 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_assign_landing);

        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
        yesSure = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sure);
        staffVie = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.staff);

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        staffName = pref.getString("staff_name", null);
        staffPhone = pref.getString("staff_number", null);
        resSlno = pref.getString("current_slno", null);
        staffVie.setText(staffName);

        yesSure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendSMSMessage();
            }
        });

    }

    protected void sendSMSMessage()
    {

        message = "New alert " + resSlno;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS:
                {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(staffPhone, null, message, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
    }
}

 else
  {
   SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(staffPhone, null, message, null, null);
        //add this else part
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

> You havent added the else part if permission is already granted.. just add this..